# Wrong Binding on Datagrid?

Tags: c#

My problem is that in a window on WPF I've got a Datagrid with some Bindings like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
                Width="100"
                CTHAUtil:DataGridColumnUtil.Name="CODIGO"
                Binding="{Binding CODIGO, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                DisplayIndex="{Binding ConfiguracionArticulos[Codigo].ORDEN, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=0}"
                Header="{Binding Path=Traducciones[CODIGO], Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=Código}"
                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CTHAGridHeaderStyle}" />
```

My problem is that data of the rows don't agree with bindable column so... for example If I got ORder Column and NameColum, data of NameColumn Appears in OrderColumn instead of NameColumn. Special mention that user can change DisplayIndex of columns.

Thank you,

Jose Manuel Luengo

Comment: So why is this? How did you end up with your data column names in your data container being different to your code/the data in your container being in the wrong columns? You made both of these things (you wrote the bindings, you filled the data into the container) so you can make them agree, no? We can't decide which you should change to make them agree but you're going to need to change one of them

Comment: Nono. My xaml is working well, but my data (It's only readonly on datagrid) is on wrong columns and I don't Know where  or what It's wrong with this...